# Time Complexity when a function only runs at the end of a loop?

Tags: time-complexity

If you have a function with linear complexity that only runs once at the end of a loop what will be the complexity of the final function?

```
def f(n):
    for i in range(0,n):
        if i==n-1:
            some_linear_complexity_function()
    return
```

Will the complexity be 0(n) or O(n^2)?
Thank you.

Comment: `O(n + m)`, where `m` is the dimensionality of the `some_linear_complexity_function`. If `m == n`, then this simplifies to `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you have defined is virtually equivalent to the following code:

```
def f(n):
    for i in range(0,n-1):
        continue            # do nothing
    some_linear_complexity_function()
    return
```

Now, assuming that `some_linear_complexity_function` is dependent on the same `n` as the `for` loop, the time complexity of `f(n)` would be `O(n)`.

However, if `some_linear_complexity_function` is dependent on some other value `m`, the time complexity of `f(n)` would actually be `O(max(m,n))`.